# XSLT adds unwanted linebreaks

Tags: html, css, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Im trying to generate HTML output with xslt and for that i use the Apache Formatting Objects Processor Version 2.3.

Each `<text>` element in the input file represents a line on a DIN A4 Page so the following input is a sentence that extends over 2 lines:

```xml
<text>This is a longer text where every line will be written into a span html element and somehow there will</text>
<text>be added a line break where there is none</text>
```

My XSLT template looks like:

```xml
<xsl:template match="text">
  <div>
    <span>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The desired output is:

```html
<div><span>This is a longer text where every line will be written into a span html element and somehow there will</span></div>
<div><span>be added a line break where there is none</span></div>
```

But what i get is:

```html
<div><span>This is a longer text where every line will be written into a span html element and
                  somehow there will</span></div>
<div><span>be added a line break where there is none</span></div>
```

My css:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

As i am using css for my `span` styling with the property `white-space: pre;` this looks pretty weird in the output as the `somehow there will` is somewhere in between those word of the second line.

Comment: Which xslt-processor are you using?
Could you show <xsl:output/> element you use.
I suppose a max line-length  is active while formatting your output.

Comment: You may have pruned away the problem.   Create and post a minimal but complete [mcve] that can be run to illustrate the issue.  Note that there's a good chance that any tool you're depending upon to generate HTML just won't care  about pleasing your HMTL source format aesthetic preference -- whitespace is consolidated and wouldn't affect rendering in the shown desired output, for example.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using the Apache FOP processor when you want HTML output.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed i did not make use of any `<xsl:output/>` element that was my fault i guess...
@MichaelKay what's wrong with it? I use it for creating pdf but its also an xslt processor so why not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try (assuming an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later) to use `<xsl:output method="html" suppress-indentation="span"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the food for thought. I could solve it now by using `<xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>`

Comment: I downloaded the latest saxonHE12.jar and it's also working well with your solution `suppress-indentation="span"`.
Before i used SaxonHE9

Comment: In theory that setting should probably work in any XSLT 3 processor which for Saxon means 9.8 and later but there were some (now fixed) bugs found which prevented it from working, see https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5018 and https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3841

Comment: I think I will use `<indent="no"/>` anyway, because I don't need indentations in the output anyway. I just wanted to see if it works and it does not hurt to bring the Saxon on the current stand :P

Answer (score 1):

The rules for the HTML output method in XSLT (§7.3 of https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/) say:

> When outputting a sequence of whitespace characters in the instance of
> the data model, within an element where whitespace characters are
> treated normally (but not in elements such as `pre` and `textarea`), the
> HTML output method MAY represent it using any sequence of whitespace
> characters that will be treated in the same way by an HTML user agent.

This doesn't allow for use of custom white-space settings in the CSS. The HTML serializer is allowed to assume that it multiple whitespace characters (including newlines) are going to be rendered in the same way as a single space, except in elements such as `pre` and `textarea`. With the developments that have taken place in CSS, this assumption is clearly no longer justified.

The rules in §7.4.3 spell out more precisely what is allowed when the `indent` parameter takes its default value of `yes`; it's less clear exactly what the rules are when `indent=no`. And of course this is 3.1, if you're using a 1.0 processor then it's all much more vague (remember that CSS had hardly been invented when XSLT 1.0 came out).

I'm completely confused by the references in your question to XSL-FO, given that you seem to be producing HTML output. I would suggest using an XSLT 3.0 processor, and either setting `indent=no`, or using the `suppress-indentation` parameter to suppress whitespace adjustment in specific elements.

Comment: Hi Michael
I am sometimes a little unfortunate in my formulations precisely because I am not 100% familiar with the subject. 
I can try to explain to you what I am doing:

Comment: I have a report in XML structure which I originally convert to PDF via self-written XSL-FO templates using Apache FOP.
But now I need an HTML output in addition to the PDF, which is why I had the idea to create a so-called [intermediate format](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/intermediate.html) via the FOP first.
I then take this intermediate format as input and transform it to HTML using another XSL-FO script.

I hope this is understandable and I am really grateful for tips.